# Sorting list based on values in C#

Tags: c#

I have a generic list with 2 parameters.

List name - Details

It contains ID and NAME

**Current Order:List - Details**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 234 | Apple |
| 324 | Orange |
| 335 | null |
| 432 | Kiwi |
| 231 | Apple |
| 345 | null |
| 326 | Orange |
| 327 | null |
| 454 | Kiwi |
| 228 | Apple |
| 329 | Orange |

I want the Details list to first have Apple values, then Orange values ,then Kiwi values and then null values

**Expected Order: List - Details**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 228 | Apple |
| 231 | Apple |
| 234 | Apple |
| 324 | Orange |
| 326 | Orange |
| 329 | Orange |
| 432 | Kiwi |
| 454 | Kiwi |
| 327 | null |
| 335 | null |
| 345 | null |

```
var sortedList = Details.OrderBy(a=> a.Name == 'Apple')
       .ThenBy(x => x.Name == 'Orange')
       .ThenBy(y=> y.Name == 'Kiwi')
       .ToList();
```

Tried this but it is not sorting as expected.

Comment: `.OrderBy` does not *change* the list, but returns a new collection that is sorted.

Comment: "Tried this but it is not working." That doesn't really help us much. What do you see vs what you expect to see? Please provide a [mcve]. (I'd suggest that ordering by the index of `a.Name` in a list would be more scalable, mind you.)

Comment: Ordering by a `bool` will sort `false` before `true`. Use `OrderByDescending` / `ThenByDescending` to sort the `true` values first.

Comment: @crashmstr, I don't get the expected sorted collection

Comment: OrderBy name==apple doesn't sort "apple" first, but whether or not the name is "apple". And then the non-matches sort first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a Score function mapping the Name to an int, someting like

```
int Score(string name)
{
   switch (name)
   {
       case "Apple": return 1;
       case "Orange": return 2;
       case "Kiwi": return 3;
       default: return 4;
   } 
}
```

and then do `Details.OrderBy(a => Score(a.Name))`.

Comment: This method will sort the Names but I also want the sorted names to have Ids in asc order. All apples should have Ids in increasing order, then all oranges should have Ids in increasing order and so on

Comment: Then add an `.ThenBy(a => a.ID)`

Answer (score 0):

This is why IComparer exists...

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;

  public MyClass(int id, string name)
  {
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
  }
}

public class CustomComparer : IComparer<MyClass>
{
  public static readonly Dictionary<string, int> Hierarchy = new() { { "Apple", 0 }, { "Orange", 1 }, { "Kiwi", 2 } };
  public int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y)
  {
    if (x.Name == y.Name) return x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id); // two nulls are equal
    if (x.Name == null) return 1;
    if (y.Name == null) return -1;
    if (Hierarchy.ContainsKey(x.Name) && Hierarchy.ContainsKey(y.Name))
      return Hierarchy[x.Name].CompareTo(Hierarchy[y.Name]);
    throw new Exception("Object Name not recognised");
  }
}
```

:
:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>
{
  new MyClass(234, "Apple"), new MyClass(324, "Orange"), new MyClass(335, null), new MyClass(432, "Kiwi"),
  new MyClass(231, "Apple"), new MyClass(345, null), new MyClass(326, "Orange"), new MyClass(327, null),
  new MyClass(454, "Kiwi"), new MyClass(228, "Apple"), new MyClass(329, "Orange")
};

list.Sort(new CustomComparer());

foreach (var entry in list)
  Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Id}, {entry.Name}");
```

Giving

```
228, Apple
231, Apple
234, Apple
324, Orange
326, Orange
329, Orange
432, Kiwi
454, Kiwi
327,
335,
345,
```